# Java NDE (Nullsoft Database Engine) Controller

Tags: java, database

I have a big problem: I want to access the Winamp Media Library, so read and write from the database.
But it is stored in a database that has an format, that is only used for Winamp: The Nullsoft Database Engine.

After a lot of research, I found no helpful information on the internet.

Sources, that might be helpful to solve this issue are:

[A Google project, but there are no equivalent functions embedded within the Java libraries](http://code.google.com/p/ndephp/wiki/NDEFormat)

[And the originally sources with specifications](http://gutenberg.free.fr/fichiers/SDK%20Winamp/nde_specs_v1.txt)

If you've got any idea about how to decode this database format or if you have access to the ml_playlists.dll source code, feel free to reply to my question ;)

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If anybody's got some information how to decode this database format or has access to Winamp ml_playlists.dll source code ;)

Comment: That should be in your "question" rather than in a comment. Edit your question so people can read it and actually know exactly what you're looking for.